# How do I know what desktop environment is being used with ansible?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, ubuntu-16.04

I have printed out the facts for the host with:

```
 - name: Display all variables/facts known for a host
   debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]
```

How do I know what the desktop environment is?

The closest I found was:

```
"COLORTERM": "gnome-terminal",
```

I was using this condition

```
ansible_env["SESSIONTYPE"] == "gnome-session"
```

But when running as `sudo` with `become` that fact is not present

Answer (score 0):

You might need to design your own facts module if this is important to you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but you could do use a `shell` block and do `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

```yaml
- name: Get Desktop
  shell:
    cmd: "echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"
  register: current_desktop

- name: Debug
  debug:
    msg: "Desktop is {{ current_desktop.stdout }}"
```

Under Fedora 38, running Gnome, that outputs "GNOME"